# Space of Curves Orthogonal to a Vector Field

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, vectors, vector-analysis, surfaces

Suppose we have a smooth (unit) vector field $v:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$. 
I am interested in properties of the family of surfaces orthogonal to $v$; i.e. the set of all possible space curves orthogonal to $v$.

One source I have looked at it is Aminov, Yu. *Geometry of Vector Fields*, 2000, in which this construct is called the *non-holonomic manifold*. However, there is not as much detail about it as I would like, particularly geometric or even physical interpretations.

Does anybody know of other ways to characterize such surfaces?
I am obviously interested in the surfaces generated by this construct from a differential geometric perspective, but since every point has an infinite number of such space curves going through it, I was wondering if there were variational or functional analytic ways of looking at it as well (i.e. analyzing it as a space of functions).

Comment: I really like this question, but I'm not sure the space curves orthogonal to $v$ passing through a given point form a surface orthogonal to $v$. For example, consider a helix-shaped vector field with its axis along $z$. Every line through the origin in the $xy$ plane is orthogonal to the vector field, but the $xy$ plane itself is not.

Comment: This is the problem of integrating a [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(differential_geometry)) - a good place to start reading might be the Frobenius theorem. In this case the distribution is simply the orthogonal complement of $v$, and the integrability condition will reduce to something like $v \times \nabla \times v = 0$ - i.e. the curl of $v$ must be everywhere parallel to $v$ for such surfaces to exist.

Comment: @Rahul thanks; you're right though, certainly there should be some conditions for existence.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis That looks very interesting and promising, thank you. If someone wants to elaborate on this and make an answer, I'd appreciate it :)